# blinking in two elements with ng-show and opposite expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two elements that only one of them needs to be visible.
They're display is controlled via the `ng-show` directive, and their expression is opposite, namely one has `ng-show="shouldshow"` and the other has `ng-show="!shouldshow".`

It works as expected but with a small side effect, when the shouldshow changes there's a short period that both elements are displayed or both elements are not displayed. As these two elements are shown side by side with other elements around them this messes up the page layout during that **blink**.

This behavior is visible with some browsers, not all.

Ideas?

Comment: Forgot to mention that both elements are of the same size, and as a fallback I'm thinking of positioning both elements on top of each other , and instead of using ng-show write a custom directive that tweaks with their vibisibility. Will this work? Is there a more native approach?

Comment: have you tried ng-if??

Comment: Haven't tried ng-if, but ng-if will probably lead to even worst blinking as it will destroy and recreate their DOM tree and not just tweak with their display.Destroying their DOM will also lead to destroying all the scopes of any child directive...

Comment: yes ng-if will destroy the children directives attached by recreating the DOM however using ng-if or ng-show depends on your use case but if you do not want to use ng-if then you can try ng-class, something like ng-class="{hidden: shouldShow}" and change the 'shouldShow variable' in $timeout ?

Comment: Some browsers? Which? What are you showing/hiding? How? I tried this https://jsbin.com/rukaxaboce/edit?html,js,output in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. They don't (visibly at least) show up at the same time.

Comment: Tried reproducing with your jsbin sample, tweaked it to match my code, doesn't reproduce.... It happened with IE11, not sure why I can't reproduce the same behavior not within my app. Maybe its a matter of load and number of watches, or maybe some special page layout, or maybe the usual random quirks of IE. Giving up.